# How to use hci_write_local_name?

Tags: c, bluetooth, bluez

I have tried (the following could would be in `int main(/*...*/)`..

```
int a = hci_get_route(NULL);
if(a < 0)
{
  return 1;
}

int b = hci_open_dev(a);
if(b < 0)
{
  return 1;
}

if(hci_write_local_name(b, "abcd", 0) < 0)
{
  return 1;
}

return 0;
```

However.. hci_write_local_name is reached, but fails (thus 1 is returned).

Answer (score 0):

Ok. Apparently in hci.c errno is accounted for (see https://github.com/Vudentz/BlueZ/blob/master/lib/hci.c#L1112).

I checked what errno was, which was 1 (i.e. "permission denied").

Running my application with `sudo` solved this issue.